# Running QUnit-Metro in Win 8 JavaScript Application, why is "test" undefined?

Tags: microsoft-metro, qunit

My entire default page is listed below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Readingz</title>

        <!-- WinJS references -->
        <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/base.js"></script>
        <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/ui.js"></script>

        <!-- Readingz references -->
        <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/default_tests.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/qunitmetro.js"></script>

        <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/css/qunitmetro-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Content goes here</p>

        <!-- This is for testing only. It goes away when application is ready to ship. -->
        <div id="qunit"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I keep getting the error that test is undefined. It looks like I have it listed above in the default.html page that the application starts with. I've added QUnit-Metro via Nuget, so I'm not really sure if I need to make some other type of association at this point, and even the ReSharper/Visual Studio enabled intellisense shows test as a valid function to call.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML looks strange;

```
<script src="/js/default_tests.js"></script>
<script src="/js/qunitmetro.js"></script>
```

This includes the script you want tested *before* importing qunitmetro.js which has all the definitions. Try reversing those two script lines and things should work better.

Comment: Doh! That's what it was!

Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes. Much appreciated. Cheers.